# How to do proportionate image gallery supporting both horizontal and vertical aspects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to make an image remain proportionate even when the viewport or parent element's aspect ratio changes.

So far I have **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/6y2qjxm0/8/)** fiddle which utilises certain techniques for setting an image as a fullscreen background. Unfortunately once it gets to a certain size it overflows and parts of the image are hidden.

### HTML

```
<div class="full-screen">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.full-screen {
      position: fixed; 
      top: -50%; 
      left: -50%; 
      width: 200%; 
      height: 200%;
}
.full-screen img {
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      margin: auto; 
      min-width: 50%;
      min-height: 50%;
}
```

Ideally I never want the image to crop, I always want it to occupy either it's full width or full height depending on the aspect ratio.

Here's an image which will hopefully make it easier to understand:

[image]

If this isn't possible with CSS alone, how could you calculate the resize using jQuery?

I've looked at posts on here like his one:

[Proportionally resize image based on parent div size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133877/proportionally-resize-image-based-on-parent-div-size?rq=1)

Suggesting I set the height of the image to `auto`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If using the image as `background` is an option, you could achieve that by `background-size: contain;` declaration: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6y2qjxm0/9/

Comment: @HashemQolami It would be great if I could but unfortunately they have to be `<img>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of min-width and min-height, use max-width and max-height in .full-screen img.

min-width means the size won't shrink below that width (and the same for height, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you have a fiddle to demonstrate it working because I can't get it to work?